# Wait for last created process (daemon which forks) to end

Tags: bash

I'm writing a wrapper script to use in inittab. 
This script starts a daemon and waits for it to terminate.

Here's what I have currently:

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/local/bin/mydaemon --lots_of_params_here
while kill -0 `echo $!` 2> /dev/null; do sleep 1; done;
```

The problem is with the second line; it just returns immediately. If I instead do:

```
while kill -0 `pgrep mydaemon` 2> /dev/null; do sleep 1; done;
```

It all works fine, but this isn't a good solution for me as I have other scripts with the prefix `mydaemon`.

What am I doing wrong?

## EDIT:

The problem seems to be related to the daemon fork(). So, I always get the parent pid in `$!`. I'm looking for ways to solve this problem. Maybe I should use pid files and have `mydaemon` write its pid there.

Comment: Can you make your daemon not fork ? If you anyway need this script running while your daemon is running, just launch your daemon in the background with the '&' operator in the shell script, and don't make the daemon fork. (In which case you can also use the shell 'wait' command instead of a loop polling the daemon for still being around.

Comment: I never thought about this. But isn't double forking daemons standard good practice (to be sure the daemon started successfully and detach from terminal)?

Comment: Perhaps. but your requirement isn't to detach from a terminal, but to have the daemon running in the background in a script - so that's what your daemon should do. If you need both usecases, have your daemon take a command line parameter that tells it to fork (or not).

Comment: Thanks, that looks like a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following way to get through your issue.

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/local/bin/mydaemon --lots_of_params_here &
wait $!
```

`wait` command will wait till the process completes and comes out.

If you are looking for to wait after some other commands then you can store the `PID` in any other variable and use that.

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/local/bin/mydaemon --lots_of_params_here &
mypid=$!
### Some other commands
wait $mypid
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Sriharsha. Your solution will work for most programs (as would mine in the original question). Unfortunately this wont work with daemons that fork as I mention in my edit.